# Advanced Shell Script menu

Tags: linux, menu, shell

I am writing a menu driven shell script and I have yes / no menu right now.

I want a menu like below :

```
    1) All                     [ ]    
    2) Config web server       [ ]
    3) Add Source files        [X]
    4) Restart Services        [ ]
    5) Apply file permissions  [ ]
```

The user should be then able to navigate up - down using arrow keys and press spacebar for selection. Pressing enter should proceed.

Has any of you seen such a menu from any opensource installation script or has any idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash has the `select` builtin (which isn't so interactive, you need to input the number of the item to choose). And then there's the `whiptail` command which is a bit more involved but will do quite exactly what you want.

Comment: Wiptail does it! Cool! and Thanks! :)

Comment: To make a more complete answer, an example menu would be `whiptail --radiolist Testmenu 0 0 0  one "(Descr: Question one)" on two "(Descr: Question two)" off`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve something like this with [Zenity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) using dialog boxes.

Comment: Thanks! But it has to be on the shell :)